# Wpf using INotifyPropertyChanged and ICommand. View is not getting updated

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to bind a List of items to a Grid within a processTimeEditor00.xml view. The view model is called timeHandler and inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged interface and a button behavior buttonAddNewProcessTimeCommand inheriting from ICommand interface. I am trying to wire the process for the view to get updated every time the “Add process time” button is clicked and the List get a new element.
Here is my Model

```
public class timeItem
{
    public Int32 hours { get; set; }
    public Int32 mins { get; set; }
    public String AMPM { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my View

```
<Window x:Class="timeSetter.processTimeEditor00"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:timeSetter"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:timeSetter.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Edit process times"
    Name="processTimeEditor00Window"
    Height="337.176" Width="300">
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModels:timeHandler/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl Name="processTimesListPresenter" ItemsSource="{Binding processTimes, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="20">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding hours, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding mins, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding AMPM, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="2"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <Button x:Name="addProcessTime" Content="Add process time" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="121" Margin="10,271,0,0" Command="{Binding btnAddNewProcessTimeCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>

</Grid>
```

My ViewModel(timeHandler)

```
public class timeHandler : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private buttonAddNewProcessTimeCommand _btnAddNewProcessTimeCommand;

    public List<timeItem> processTimes { get; set; }
    public ICommand btnAddNewProcessTimeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _btnAddNewProcessTimeCommand;
        }
    }

    public timeHandler()
    {
        loadProcessTimes();
        _btnAddNewProcessTimeCommand = new buttonAddNewProcessTimeCommand(this);
    }

    public void loadProcessTimes()
    {
        timeItem[] aux = new timeItem[] 
        {
            new timeItem { AMPM="AM", hours=12, mins=35 },
            new timeItem { AMPM="PM", hours=2, mins=15 },
            new timeItem { AMPM="PM", hours=5, mins=15 }
        };
        processTimes = aux.ToList<timeItem>();
    }

    public void addProcessTime()
    {
        processTimes.Add(new timeItem { AMPM="AM", hours=12, mins=0 });
        if (PropertyChanged != null) 
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("processTimes"));

        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

Here is the command(buttonAddNewProcessTimeCommand)

```
class buttonAddNewProcessTimeCommand : ICommand
{
    private timeHandler obj;
    public buttonAddNewProcessTimeCommand(timeHandler _obj)
    {
        obj = _obj;
    }
    public Boolean CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        obj.addProcessTime();
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

But although the process are doing what expected, the view is not getting updated. Can somebody help me to find what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change processTimes to ObservableCollection. It should work. List cannot do automatic UI update. Read about ObservableCollection

```
public class timeHandler : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private buttonAddNewProcessTimeCommand _btnAddNewProcessTimeCommand;

    public ObservableCollection<timeItem> processTimes { get; set; }
    public ICommand btnAddNewProcessTimeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _btnAddNewProcessTimeCommand;
        }
    }

    class buttonAddNewProcessTimeCommand : ICommand
    {
        private timeHandler obj;
        public buttonAddNewProcessTimeCommand(timeHandler _obj)
        {
            obj = _obj;
        }
        public Boolean CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            obj.addProcessTime();
        }
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }

    public timeHandler()
    {
        loadProcessTimes();
        _btnAddNewProcessTimeCommand = new buttonAddNewProcessTimeCommand(this);
    }

    public void loadProcessTimes()
    {
        timeItem[] aux = new timeItem[]
        {
        new timeItem { AMPM="AM", hours=12, mins=35 },
        new timeItem { AMPM="PM", hours=2, mins=15 },
        new timeItem { AMPM="PM", hours=5, mins=15 }
        };
        processTimes = new ObservableCollection<timeItem>(aux);
    }

    public void addProcessTime()
    {
        processTimes.Add(new timeItem { AMPM = "AM", hours = 12, mins = 0 });
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("processTimes"));

        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

Comment: And the definition is very clear: ObservableCollection: "Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed."
THANKS AGAIN!!